# При запуске программы выкидывает ошибку

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, vector, stl

В программе выскакивает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
private:
    vector<int>obj;
public:
    Array(int mn, int mx)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        for (it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); ++it)
        {
            *it = rand() / RAND_MAX * (mx - mn) + mn;
        }
    }
int sum()
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int sum = 0;
    for (it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); ++it)
        sum += *it;
    return sum;
}

int min()
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int min = *(obj.begin());
    for (it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it < min)
            min = *it;
    }
    return min;
}

int max()
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int max = *(obj.begin());
    for (it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it > max)
            max = *it;
    }
    return max;

}

/*friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const vector<int>&v)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        out << *it << " ";
    }
    return out;
    }*/
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int mn, mx;
    cout << "Введите мин. значение диапазона: ";
    cin >> mn;
    cout << "Введите макс. значение диапазона: ";
    cin >> mx;
    Array test(mn, mx);
    int min, max, sum;
    min = test.min();
    cout << "Минимальный элемент: " << min;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В чем причина такого поведения программы?

Comment: Так вы никогда не добавляете элементы в свой вектор. А `min` и `max` у вас написаны так, что не работают с пустыми векторами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Добавил в конструктор после рандома obj.push_back(*it); Ошибка все равно выскакивает.

Comment: У вас цикл в конструкторе ни разу не выполнится, потому что ыектор изначально пустой.

Comment: Сколько, по-вашему, в `obj` должно быть элементов? Когда вы создаете `Array`?

Comment: @Harry - Уже понял что забыл указать размер вектора. А как сделать чтобы в конструкторе выделилась память под вектор из N элементов?

Comment: `Array(int mn, int mx):obj(N) { ...` Можно и указать и по умолчанию - `private: vector<int>obj(N);`

Comment: Что за ерунду вы делаете?  `obj.push_back(*it);`? Зачем? Вы же просто рушите при этом итераторы.

Comment: @Harry у меня по заданию необходимо пользоваться итераторами. Объясните пожалуйста что именно я делаю не так, и как надо делать ибо только начал учить STL и запутался

Comment: Тогда выбирайте первый вариант в моем ответе. При вставке в вектор память с элементами может быть перенесена в другое место, и все ваши итераторы  (грубо - указатели на элементы) перестают соответствовать реальности.

Comment: @Harry а N это глобальная переменная? А в остальных методах класса Array я тоже инвалидирую итераторы?

Comment: N может быть глобальной переменной, может - аргументом конструктора, если используете инициализацию `:obj(N)`. Иначе - константой, известной при компиляции, насколько я помню. При чтении вы итераторы не инвалидируете, при вставке - можете. Словом, стотрите документацию на [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) и его функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Послушайте, не пытайтесь войти в две двери одновременно - это обычно означает вмазать лбом в простенок...

Либо вы работаете с *имеющимися* элементами

```
    vector<int>obj;
public:
    Array(int mn, int mx):obj(N)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        for (it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); ++it)
        {
            *it = rand() / RAND_MAX * (mx - mn) + mn;
        }
    }
```

либо добавляете элементы в пустой вектор:

```
Array(int mn, int mx)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        obj.push_back(rand() / RAND_MAX * (mx - mn) + mn);
    }
}
```

То, что вы пытаетесь делать - `obj.push_back(*it)` - означает, что вы хотите получить по два одинаковых элемента в векторе, но на самом деле при вставке инвалидируете итератор (при перераспределении памяти).